# How to get the data for the dynamic column name in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I would like to take the column names dynamically.

```
declare
  rColNames varchar2(500);
  rColumns varchar2(4000);
  rC varchar2(4000);

BEGIN
  for i in (
    select  name, amount,days -- (More columns will be there)
    from trans_e 
    where name = 'A'
  )
  loop
    --dynamically selected column names 
    --:P2_COLS -- NAME,AMOUNT,DAYS etc...
    for colNames in
    (
      select regexp_substr(:P2_COLS,'[^,]+',1,level) rCol from dual
      connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(:P2_COLS,'[^,]+')) + 1
    )
    loop
      rColNames :=  LOWER(colNames.rCol);
      select 'i.' || rColNames into rColumns from dual; 
      rC := rC ||  rColumns ; 
    end loop;
    
    
   

  end loop;
END;
```

So I need the data from `i.days` in `rColumns`. But I am getting the `rColumns` as `i.days` instead of `i.days` value 10.

If I give `i.days` directly, I am getting the value 10. But if I am giving `'i.' || rColNames`, then I get `i.days` as an output, not the value 10.

How to get the dynamic data value from the `i` loop?

Comment: You can't easily. Your loops are a bit strange; even if this worked, `rColNames` would end up with the final string from the CSV list ('DAYS' in the example, and `rColumns` would end up with the `days` value from the last row returned by the `i` loop, if there is more than one. And then you don't do anything with the values anyway?

Comment: So i am concatenating the rColumns in the loop rC := rC ||  rColumns ;  My problem is how to get the 'i.' || rColNames data (i.days value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach may be to enumerate the columns in a case expression:

```
loop
  -- append a comma if this isn't the first column
  rC := case when rC is not null then rC || ',' end ||
    case lower(colNames.rCol)
      when 'name' then i.name
      when 'amount' then to_char(i.amount)
      when 'days' then to_char(i.days)
    end;          
end loop;
```

If you're expecting multiple rows back from the outer cursor then you need to clear `rC` before each row:

```
declare
  rC varchar2(4000);
begin
  for i in (
    select  name, amount,days -- (More columns will be there)
    from trans_e 
    where name = 'A'
  )
  loop
    -- clear result from previous row
    rC := null;

    --dynamically selected column names 
    --:P2_COLS -- NAME,AMOUNT,DAYS etc...
    for colNames in
    (
      select regexp_substr(:P2_COLS,'[^,]+',1,level) rCol from dual
      connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(:P2_COLS,'[^,]+')) + 1
    )
    loop
      -- append a comma if this isn't the first column
      rC := case when rC is not null then rC || ',' end ||
        case lower(colNames.rCol)
          when 'name' then i.name
          when 'amount' then to_char(i.amount)
          when 'days' then to_char(i.days)
        end;          
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi Alex Poole,   Thanks for your ideas. I have 25 columns from the query. It is like a lot of case statements. But I think, still it's a good idea. I will try to implement this approach. Thanks for your help.